# Does mouse flicking speed up the application UI (WinForms)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, desktop-application

There are rumors that the work of Win Forms applications can be accelerated by moving the mouse over the application window, and supposedly it is described here [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/priority-boosts)

edited

I know that the processes could be accelerated on windows95, but this is no longer relevant
[oldtopic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11533/why-did-moving-the-mouse-cursor-cause-windows-95-to-run-more-quickly)

As if the thread's priority is being raised and therefore the application is called more often.

Help me figure out if this is true and how to check it

Comment: The links you have provided are relative to Win95. A ancient geological era. Any way. Why do you need to know this? Do you have some performance problem to solve?

Comment: Ｍy team lead told me about it. I doubt that moving the mouse speeds up the performance of modern UI applications, so I'm trying to find out the truth

Comment: you may be able to mesure this. Write an application which solves a complex algorithem again and again and measures how long it takes to process X rounds.
Measure this a few times with and without mouse over the application window.

Answer (score 0):

This is a myth that has been disproved in environments > Windows 95. There have been a few developers that have proved this and I have tested this also in Windows 7 & Windows 10 with no improvement or acceleration in processes.